# Price of coin at purchase in coinbase wallet

Tags: transactions

I purchased some function x and shib inu weeks ago....i cant seem to figure out how to find what i paid per coin in coinbase wallet.  the value moves up and down based on current price...any one have a beginner solution?

also while trying to find an answer. I noticed in either scan under transaction fee, you can find fee at time of purchase. Or current fee. why the need for current fee? its already been paid at time of purchase?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider looking into your transaction history of Coinbase?
Pretty sure you'll find it there ;)